# SonarQube: Create PL/SQL custom rules

Tags: plsql, sonarqube, plsqldeveloper

I'd like to learn how to create custom rules for the SonarQube PL/SQL Plugin, however the link on the official Sonar website is "broken". Clicking on it opens a page with a "The page you are looking for does not exist" error. Does anyone know if it is possible to find documentation on this elsewhere?

I know this might not be the place to ask these types of questions but I don't know where else to ask and maybe someone will know. Thank you.

This is the link about the plugin in, clicking on "custom rules" from the Advanced Usage section leads to the non existent page error.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules

The broken link on the PL/SQL plugin page has been fixed. Points to the very same page now. Thanks for reporting that.